# What is the significance of the 3 Delta ships shown on Stage 1?

Tags: danmaku-unlimited-2

At the start of the game (Stage 1), there were 3 Delta Ships. One of them gets destroyed later.

But the ships only showed up for Stage 1, and there was no description about them. What are the ships there for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a [Steam Forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/280560/discussions/0/540736965889891563/), someone asked nearly the same question as you.  Someone replied that:

> Early in development, the game was suppose to have a bigger story element (inspired by Philosoma) Most of it didn't make it in the final product but I thought it was cool just to keep some of the scripted events in as flavor.

It appears there was meant to be a larger story behind the game, but it was cut out of the final product.  This makes sense since you state that they don't make another appearance.  These ships were suppose to be apart of that story.

Comment: So in short, there were just mostly for show, correct?

Comment: Well yes - but they were *suppose* to tie into a story that didn't make it into the game.